# How do I find out how many bronze badges were awarded total per tag?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

I'm working on a bronze Javascript badge and would like to know, up until today, how many people total have already gotten a gold, silver, and bronze badge for that tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look for the tag in the [list of tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). All existing tag badges are listed there as well as the number of recipients.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks much will accept later.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [one place](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers) to start, which gives you top users for a tag.

If you're nearly 100 total score (=bronze), you will see your position at the bottom of the "top users" list, which will be roughly how many have the bronze tag badge.

Or, you can [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/86070/99520/javascript-bronze-tag-badges) at data.stackexchange.com which has **just been reloaded** (11-Nov-2012)!  1,280 people had the bronze Javascript badge as of 11-Nov-2012.

Comment: ok i see, thanks a lot